# associative table for OneToMany relation

Tags: php, database-design, eloquent, database-relations, associative-table

I'm working on a subtitles bot where:

- A Movie has multiple subtitles (depending on quality and language)
- A Series has multiple seasons with multiple episodes that have multiple subtitles (same as a movie)

These are my tables (Thanks to [DaveRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom)):

[image]

The problem is, as far as I know associative tables are for many-to-many relationships (correct me if I'm wrong), I'm kinda stuck here, especially with Eloquent's belongsToMany method:

```
class Subtitle extends Model {
    public $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function SeriesEpisodes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('SeriesEpisode', null, null, 'series_episodes_subtitle');
    }


    public function Movie()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Movie');
    }
}
```

But the problem is, A Subtitle belongsToOne Episode, whereas an Episode might have many subtitles.
I was wondering how one could use associative tables for such structure.
Or should I change the structure?

Comment: @Barmar that is hasMany relationship, but that can't be achieved with the current structure. because episode and movie is not at the same table. or I've gotten the concepts wrong, I'm not good at all with database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I was trying to achieve is possible with polymorphic relationships,
2 associative tables are removed and instead 2 fields are added to subtitles table:
ex: parent_type, parent_id

then I can use:

subtitles:

```
class Subtitle extends Model {
    public $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Parent()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

series_episodes:

```
class SeriesEpisode extends Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $guarded = [];
    public function Subtitles()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Subtitle', 'Owner');
    }
}
```

movies:

```
class Movie extends Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $guarded = [];
    public function Subtitles()
    {
    return $this->morphMany('Subtitle', 'Owner');
    }
}
```

Hope it helps others.